# M&B:W AI Mesh Colors

Tags: mount-and-blade-warband

I'm editing the AI mesh, but some of the faces turn purple, or red? What does this mean? For example, I had some mesh up about a story above the ground, and it was red. The AI got stuck in a group and wouldn't walk across the bridge or stairs (same color) in the same area. Note that the AI spawned up there. When I came back to look at it again, it turned purple. What is happening?